# What does m represents in VIRT column using TOP command

Tags: rhel, process, swap, virtual-memory

When we run top command it shows all the processes information. But under VIRT column there is m written against some values **what does that m represents**, is it MB . If yes then why it is only showing 12k in SWAP Header. Because if we do total the size is much much more than 12k.

```
top - 15:43:19 up 3 days, 55 min,  2 users,  load average: 0.01, 0.08, 0.08
Tasks: 259 total,   1 running, 258 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  1.7%us,  0.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 97.8%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.1%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   8177292k total,  6988680k used,  1188612k free,   417064k buffers
Swap:  8385920k total,       12k used,  8385908k free,  4535416k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
29948 oracle    18   0  898m 269m  41m S 14.6  3.4   1:28.77 java
29947 oracle    18   0  863m 203m  34m S  1.3  2.5   0:51.60 java
29912 oracle    18   0  405m 199m  18m S  0.0  2.5   1:57.79 java
29943 oracle    18   0  376m 148m  19m S  0.0  1.9   0:18.00 java
29909 oracle    18   0  821m 104m  27m S  0.0  1.3   0:13.91 java
31008 oracle    15   0  512m  91m  28m S  0.0  1.1   0:10.28 java
30245 oracle    15   0  559m  82m  19m S  0.0  1.0   0:11.70 rwserver
29945 oracle    18   0  296m  68m  18m S  0.0  0.9   0:29.24 java
29961 oracle    17   0  298m  66m  18m S  0.0  0.8   0:10.32 java
30341 oracle    15   0  554m  64m  24m S  0.0  0.8   0:08.26 java
29936 oracle    18   0  302m  61m  16m S  0.3  0.8   0:08.25 java
 2543 oracle    15   0  553m  60m  24m S  0.0  0.8   0:04.45 java
 8546 oracle    25   0  367m  56m  13m S  0.0  0.7   0:19.78 emagent
29942 oracle    17   0  307m  56m  18m S  0.0  0.7   0:08.00 java
29946 oracle    18   0  293m  53m  16m S  0.0  0.7   0:08.58 java
32324 oracle    15   0  361m  51m  22m S  0.0  0.6   0:03.21 frmweb
29905 oracle    18   0  290m  48m  15m S  0.0  0.6   0:06.02 java
 5014 oracle    15   0  355m  45m  23m S  0.0  0.6   0:02.16 frmweb
 1135 oracle    15   0  355m  44m  22m S  0.0  0.6   0:01.90 frmweb
 4280 oracle    15   0  355m  44m  22m S  0.0  0.6   0:01.35 frmweb
 6727 oracle    15   0  353m  42m  22m S  0.0  0.5   0:00.84 frmweb
31043 oracle    16   0  452m  42m  12m S  0.0  0.5   0:03.01 java
29944 oracle    18   0  279m  42m  15m S  0.0  0.5   0:05.30 java
29941 oracle    15   0 98716  40m 4356 S  0.0  0.5   0:20.50 webcached
 8682 oracle    15   0 72536  29m  12m S  0.0  0.4   0:01.59 frmweb
```

Answer (score 2):

Virtual addresses are only backed by physical memory and swap when required. A process is welcome to allocate as much memory as it likes, and the system is welcome to not actually give it that memory until it is needed. See the `malloc(3)` man page, **NOTES** section for details.